# How to write multiple csv files to specific directory in R within a by (group) function?

Tags: r

I am attempting to export multiple files by group of my data frame. The following code works great, but the files are exported into the working directory. I need to export these to a different directory: `different_folder`

```
by(df, df$Subject, FUN=function(i) write.csv(i, paste0(i$Subject[1], ".csv"), quote = F))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. It uses `file.path` to form a file name in a OS independent way. From the documentation, my emphasis.

> file.path {base}
> Construct Path to File
> Description
> Construct the path to a file from components in a **platform-independent** way.

Note also that I have added a `verbose` argument, defaulting to `FALSE`. Remove it from the call (`verbose = TRUE`, near the end) if the screen is being cluttered by unwanted feedback.

```r
df <- iris
names(df)[5] <- "Subject"

different_folder <- "~/Temp"
by(df, df$Subject, FUN = function(i, verbose = FALSE) {
  outfile <- file.path(different_folder, paste0(i[1, "Subject"], ".csv"))
  if(verbose) cat("output file:", outfile, "\n")
  write.csv(i, outfile, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}, verbose = TRUE)
#> output file: ~/Temp/setosa.csv 
#> output file: ~/Temp/versicolor.csv 
#> output file: ~/Temp/virginica.csv
#> df$Subject: setosa
#> NULL
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> df$Subject: versicolor
#> NULL
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> df$Subject: virginica
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to also add the directory to the path you are giving:

```
df <- data.table(1:20, 
             1:20, 
             Subject= rep(c("A", "B"), each= 10),
             directory= rep(c("test1", "test2"), each= 10))
dir.create("test1")
dir.create("test2")
by(df, df$Subject, FUN=function(i) write.csv(i, paste0(i$directory[1], "/", i$Subject[1], ".csv"), quote = F))
```

Note that the directory will be relative to your working directory. Providing full path can be safer.
Make sure that the directory exists before running your code

Comment: I like the simplicity, but it does not work. I have tried this.

Comment: Thats how I generally do it, so there must be another problem. Would you provide us with a piece of your df?

Comment: this code writes the file to the same folder and it does not export the date. Instead it outputs ```,x
1,C:/User/My_name/different_folder```

Comment: Because you are missing a "/" at the end of your directory. Hence the name will be "C:/User/My_name/different_foldermyfile.csv". try paste0(my_folder, "/", my_file, ".csv")

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, and this chunk of code works for me